# Running Multiple Commands in CMD.EXE from C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, command

I am attempting to 1. run a cd command and 2. execute a node.js executable that takes in two filenames through the command window.

The following code is embedded in a for loop so the variable names for the filename extension variables change:

```
command_line = "/C cd C:/Users/esimons/Documents/Software/Serial_GUIC#/ComputerToArduino/images/TraxSecur-Node/TraxSecur-Node/ & node main.js " + image_extension + " " + UID_extension;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", command_line);
```

I have tried splitting up the commands using a & which I saw on another thread but it is not working.

Using alternative approach:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:/Users/esimons/Documents/Software/Serial_GUIC#/ComputerToArduino/images/TraxSecur-Node/TraxSecur-Node/";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("node main.js " + image_extension + " " + UID_extension);
p.Close();
```

Solution:
The above code works! Restart you system if you have recently installed node.js

Comment: Why don't you start node executable directly ?

Comment: I think, you'll need a space here `/&`. Also, which error did you get?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added a space and it still didn't produce the correct output. Is there a difference between what I am opening up here (cmd.exe) versus what I am opening the command prompt from windows desktop and typing in the above commands?

Comment: @Aybe how would I do that? that seems like that would be an easier solution

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @colinodowd have you tried to redirect standard error or output to see the actual error message or output?

Comment: @aybe so i tried something similar to that and I got no results. It is only working when i manually type the command into the command window. My code is above

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I am not getting any error it just isnt producing the same output as when i type the commands in manually

Comment: Why do you need `cd` command? maybe make sense just to specify a working directory?

Comment: You can use startinfo and then lauch the process

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/Users/esimons/Documents/Software/Serial_GUIC#/ComputerToArduino/images/TraxSecur-Node/TraxSecur-Node/";
        startInfo.FileName = "node.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments= "main.js " + image_extension + " " + UID_extension;

        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

Comment: @user964829 That didn't work. I tried removing the .exe after node as well and it didn't work that way either

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski check out my updated code above. I removed the CD line and added in my working directory. Still does not work

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski so I just realized that my output has been saying: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I had recently installed node.js and had not restarted my system. After restarting, it worked.

Comment: @colinodowd Just checking to know, if you got a chance to try the below solution ?

Comment: @Clint i didn't because the above solution was working I just didnt know i needed to restart my system after downloading node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:/Users/esimons/Documents/Software/Serial_GUIC#/ComputerToArduino/images/TraxSecur-Node/TraxSecur-Node/";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("node main.js " + image_extension + " " + UID_extension);
p.Close();
```